# C - how to use sscanf with a formatted string?

Tags: c

I have a string which I have successfully formatted like this (Yes, the whitespaces are inconsistent):

```
|Prague| |Sunny|
|Prague| |Cloudy|
|Prague| |Rain|
|New York||Sunny|
|New York||No data|
|New York||Rain|
```

I can change the character `|` easily to any other char btw.

I want to assign each text this way:

char city; => Prague

char weather; => Sunny

etc.

I tried using sscanf like this: `sscanf(input, "|%s||%s|", city, weather);` but it doesn't work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Maybe some regex would help?

The wrong result I'm getting is this by the way:

```
Prague, ����
Prague, ����
Prague, ����
....
```

Comment: The compiler warnings that you must be getting should point out half of the problem with that. The other part is that the `%s` format specifier reads a string delimited by whitespace, so it won't match a multi-word like "*New York*". You could use an include character set, instead, see the `scanf` [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

Comment: the `%s` in `sscanf` match any non-white space characters and if your city has one it'll fail, either you have to use `regex` or it's simple to write your own parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because there is a space between the 2 `|`'s.

You can ignore any characters between the first ending `|` and the second starting `|` by adding the `%*[^|]` which means: "Ignore everything until you find a `|`.

`sscanf(input, "|%s|%*[^|]|%s|", city, weather);`

But if you could have two or more words you should use a different specifier than `%s`:

`sscanf(input, "|%[^|]|%*[^|]|%[^|]|", city, weather);`

Comment: sscanf(input, "|%s|%*[^|]|%s|", city, weather) works, but only when there are multiple words - would it be possible to modify it so it would work with one AND multiple words? :)

Comment: there was a typo. check the last line that I've updated

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
char *
```

instead of

```
char
```

> char

is only a single character, but you'll need a pointer.